# How do I retrieve a model in Vertex AI?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai

I defined a training job:

```
job = aiplatform.AutoMLTextTrainingJob(...
```

then I created a model by running the job:

```
model = job.run(...
```

It worked fine but it is now the next day and the variable `model` was in a Jupyter notebook and no longer exists. I have tried to get it back with:

```
from google.cloud import aiplatform_v1beta1

def sample_get_model():
    client = aiplatform_v1beta1.ModelServiceClient()

    model_id=id_of_training_pipeline
    name= f'projects/{PROJECT}/locations/{REGION}/models/{model_id}'
    
    request = aiplatform_v1beta1.GetModelRequest(name=name)
    response = client.get_model(request=request)
    print(response)

sample_get_model()
```

I have also tried the id of v1 of the model created in place of `id_of_training_pipeline` and I have tried `/pipelines/pipeline_id`

but I get:
`E0805 15:12:36.784008212   28406 hpack_parser.cc:1234]       Error parsing metadata: error=invalid value key=content-type value=text/html; charset=UTF-8`

(`PROJECT` and `REGION` are set correctly).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/samples/aiplatform-get-model-sample#aiplatform_get_model_sample-python) Google code which works.